# Firebase functions for logging in users are not being recognized. Specifically signInWithEmailAndPassword()

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I've decided to use Firebase for handling authentication for my website. However, even after successful importation of the required code to begin the project, like the apiKey and such, a lot of functions within firebase aren't being recognized.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.6.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.6.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/3.5.2/firebaseui.js"></script>
```

I have these scripts above my apiKey area and all of that, along with having my own file below the entire `var firebaseConfig` field.

However, in my auth.js file, the function signInWithEmailAndPassword() is not being recognized at all (see linked image for editor view). And I cant find any solutions thus far.  [Picture of my api key and all of that to show everything's layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vU0Zt.png)

[Editor view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTMFr.png)

Comment: when you say its "not being recognized" - are you getting an error saying `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword` is not a function? or some other error?

Comment: @JaromandaX my editor says 'Unresolved function or method' which is the same thing within the console of my browser as well.